# Как выводит toast не в классе активити?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли и, если можно то как выводить toast не в классе, наследуемой от активити, а в классе, наследуемом от SurfaceView? А если нельзя, то чем можно заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Класс `SurfaceView` наследуется от `View` и соответсвенно имеет метод `getContext()` необходимый для создания объектов `Toast`.